# how to trace the origin of ReactJS compiled files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently looking through a medium sized project and I was wondering if there was an efficient/quick way to determine the origin of a compiled/generated file in a ReactJS folder. Alternatively, what kind of name would be a viable possibility, according to best practices?

In the `compiled` folder there is a `car-page.min.js` file which gives 5 errors in the browser console. However in the `src` folder, there is no `car-page.js` file.

FYI: the thrown error is: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined*

Comment: Without knowing how you're compiling or minimizing it'll be really difficult to help. In general, minimized files come from non-minimized files. No tools I've used will automagically break up files.

Comment: I'm a newbie myself, so I'm afraid I can't offer much more information. Thanks for your opinion regardless.